# Does the cost basis increase by reinvestment of investment income in Roth IRA?

Tags: united-states, taxes, roth-ira, cost-basis

In regular brokerage  account, the cost basis increases by reinvestment of investment income.

I guess it is the same case in Roth IRA? I am not sure, because I don't know if there is some rule that says no for reason that I don't know.

If it is the same case, since tax forms such as 1099-xxx do not report investment income from Roth IRA as long as they are not withdrawn from the Roth IRA, I think the only source for updating cost basis is the monthly statement of the Roth IRA?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

> **Earnings on investments within your Roth IRA that 
>   are reinvested within your Roth IRA do 
>   not increase your basis in your Roth IRA.**

Your basis in your Roth IRA is the *total amount of post-tax money* that
you have contributed to your Roth IRA.  There are three categories
here.

- The amount that you have contributed directly to your Roth IRA
  over the years. Remember that you did not get to deduct these
  contributions on your tax returns and so this is post-tax money.
- Any basis that you had in your Traditional IRA account that you 
  converted and transferred into your Roth IRA.  This basis is the
  sum of all the nondeductible contributions you made to your 
  Traditional IRA (and reported on Form 8606, I hope).  This is
  post-tax money since you didn't get to deduct these 
  contributions on your tax returns.
- Any other amounts that you converted from your
  Traditional IRA and transferred to your Roth IRA.
  These are typically the tax-deductible contributions 
  that you made to your Traditional IRA plus the 
  tax-deferred earnings (or losses) within the Traditional
  IRA.  You
  declared these amounts as taxable income and paid income taxes on 
  them as part of the conversion and transfer process
  and so this is also post-tax money.

Your basis is post-tax money, and you are entitled to
withdraw all or any part of it from your Roth IRA without 
having to pay income tax all over again on the amounts.
The first two categories have the advantage that they
can be withdrawn at any time without incurring the 10% 
tax penalty for early withdrawal, but the third category
will incur the 10% penalty for early withdrawal if it
is withdrawn too soon.  Can you play games with the
amounts and say that you are withdrawing one kind of
money and not the other?  No, you cannot. The IRS rules 
say that the amount withdrawn is counted against the
first category (direct contributions), and when all that
money has been withdrawn, the rest is counted 
against the second and third 
categories in order of seniority: the oldest amounts
come out first.  Any **earnings** within your Roth IRA
are deemed to have been withdrawn only after your 
*entire basis* (remember: basis means post-income tax money that you
contributed to your Roth IRA) has been withdrawn
completely.  These earnings are tax-free and penalty-free
as long as they are a *Qualified Distribution* (meaning
after the later of 5 years after account was opened
and age 59.5 or meeting one of the exceptions) but
are subject to both income tax and 10% penalty
if they are not Qualified Distributions

To forestall your next questions, I remind you that

- In the eyes of the law, you have only one Roth IRA, and so taking
  earnings from your Roth IRA investment account in Brokerage A and investing those in your  Roth IRA investment account in Brokerage B does not
  count as a contribution and does not increase your basis. This
  case is covered by the block-quoted sentence in bold face above
  because you have only one Roth IRA in the eyes of the law, and
  the money transferred over from Brokerage A to Brokerage B is 
  entirely within your Roth IRA.
- You can update "your basis" as per your understanding using
  your monthly IRA statements in your personal money management
  software program so that you feel good (or bad) about your
  Roth IRA investments, but doing so does not change what the 
  law regards as your basis in your Roth IRA.
- There is no constitutional requirement that tax laws have to
  have a rationale, or be reasonable according to what you or
  anyone else thinks is reasonable, or agree with what you
  have recorded in your personal money management program as
  "your basis" in your Roth IRA.
- If you don't like the law, don't ask in this forum why the
  law is the way it is; we have no answer that will satisfy
  you.  Instead, write to your Congress-critter
  demanding that the law be revised to read the way you want it
  to read. If your Congress-critter does not agree to do what you
  want, an election is coming up in a few months' time.

Comment: One point on the Roth 'Basis' - The deposited amount can always be withdrawn tax/penalty free. Growth can not, not can the funds from Trad IRA conversions. So, whatever terminology one wishes to use, there are multiple numbers to track, and if asked what the basis is, the correct answer is "for what purpose?"

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: "not can the funds from Trad IRA conversions" Not true. Non-taxable parts of the conversion can be withdrawn tax and penalty free at any time. Taxable parts of the conversion can be withdrawn tax and penalty free after 5 years.

Comment: I chose my words carefully (aside from the typo - the second 'not' was supposed to be 'nor'). The delay of 5 years is a "not always," which creates the need to track separately. By the way, I read the 5yr rule in some places as 5yrs or age 59.5 whichever is second, where others read as whichever comes first. A clarification would be great.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer  According to Pub 590, p.62, bottom of right column, a Qualified Distribution (meaning no income tax and no penalty) is one that occurs 1. more than 5 years after the first deposit into the Roth IRA **and** 2, meets one of four criteria a.age at least 59.5, b. disability, c. death of owner, d. "first home" exceptions (as listed on p. 49 of Pub 590) which also includes medical and educational expenses.  So it **is** the later of 5 years and 59.5 years of age, not the earlier (or just 5 years as user102008 claims). See my revised answer too.

Comment: Once again, Dilip, I tip my hat to you.